# binary search tree impelementation and java

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree

I am trying to implement BST algorithm using Cormen's pseudo code yet having issue.

Here is my Code for Node:

```
public class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
    int value;

    Node(int value){
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;  
    }
}
```

and for the Bstree:

```
public class Btree {
    Node root;

    Btree(){
        this.root = null;
    }

    public static void inorderWalk(Node n){
        if(n != null){
            inorderWalk(n.left);
            System.out.print(n.value + " ");
            inorderWalk(n.right);
        }
    }

    public static Node getParent(Btree t, Node n){
        Node current = t.root;
        Node parent = null;


        while(true){
            if (current == null)
                return null;

            if( current.value == n.value ){
                break;
            }

            if (current.value > n.value){
                parent = current;
                current = current.left;
            }
            else{ //(current.value < n.value)
                parent = current;
                current = current.right;
            }       
        }
        return parent;
    }


    public static Node search(Node n,int key){
        if(n == null || key == n.value ){
            return n;
        }
        if(key < n.value){
            return search(n.left,key);
        }
        else{
            return search(n.right,key);

        }
    }

    public static Node treeMinimum(Node x){
        if(x == null){
            return null;
        }


        while(x.left != null){
            x = x.left;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static Node treeMaximum(Node x){
        if(x == null){
            return null;
        }

        while(x.right != null){
            x = x.right;
        }
        return x;   
    }

    public static Node treeSuccessor(Btree t,Node x){
        if (x.right == null){
            return treeMinimum(x.right);
        }
        Node y = getParent(t,x);
        while(y != null && x == y.right){
            x = y;
            y = getParent(t,y);
        }
        return y;   
    }

    public static Btree insert(Btree t,Node z){
        Node y = null;
        Node x = t.root;

        while(x != null){
            y = x;
            if(z.value < x.value)
                x = x.left;
            else
                x = x.right;
        }
        Node tmp = getParent(t,z);
        tmp = y;
        if(y == null){
            t.root = z;
        }
        else if(z.value < y.value)
            y.left = z;
        else
            y.right = z;

        return t;
    }


    public static Btree delete(Btree t,Node z){
        Node y,x;
        if (z.left == null || z.right == null)
            y = z;
        else
            y = treeSuccessor(t,z);

        if (y.left != null)
            x = y.left;
        else
            x = y.right;
        if (x != null){
            Node tmp = getParent(t,x);
            tmp = getParent(t,y);
        }

        if (getParent(t,y) == null ){
            t.root = x;
        }
        else{
            if( y == getParent(t,y).left ){
                getParent(t,y).left = x;
            }
            else{
                getParent(t,y).right = x;

            }
    }
        if(y != z){
            z.value = y.value;
        }
    return t;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Btree test = new Btree(); 
    Node n1 = new Node(6);
    Node n2 = new Node(3);
    Node n3 = new Node(9);
    Node n4 = new Node(1);
    Node n5 = new Node(16);
    Node n6 = new Node(4);
    Node n7 = new Node(2);
    Node n8 = new Node(11);
    Node n9 = new Node(13);


    test = insert(test,n1);
    test = insert(test,n2);
    test = insert(test,n3);
    test = insert(test,n4);
    test = insert(test,n5);
    test = insert(test,n6);
    test = insert(test,n7);
    test = insert(test,n8);
    test = insert(test,n9);
    inorderWalk(test.root);
    System.out.println();
    test = delete(test,n8);
    inorderWalk(test.root);

    System.out.println();
    test = delete(test,n5);
    inorderWalk(test.root);

    System.out.println();
    test = delete(test,n2);
    inorderWalk(test.root);

    System.out.println();
    test = delete(test,n1);
    inorderWalk(test.root);




}

}
```

The main problem is with the remove part, sometimes it is working as intended, sometimes removing wrongly and sometimes null pointer exception. What can be the issue ?

Ps: this is NOT a homework

Comment: Can you provide the specific test sequence that gets the remove wrongly?  And can you provide the specific test sequence that gets the null pointer?

Comment: Given TreeMap exists in standard libraries, please explain how this isn't homework...

Comment: Side comment; in the delete method, for some if statements you use braces {}, for other if statements you don't.  You should *always* use them, it will help you avoid stepping into stupid mistakes while debugging your code, and will make your code more readable for others.

Comment: That, or only leave the braces off when the "then" part of the `if` statement follows on the same line. Not perfect, but a reasonable compromise. Coding the "then" part underneath, indented but without braces is the worst you can do.

Comment: cheers for the bracket suggestion. @Nicolas I am trying to learn the algorithm implementation, for homework I could simply copy some already existing code and use that as an HW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some immediate problems with your code: your `treeSuccessor` starts with

```
    if (x.right == null){
        return treeMinimum(x.right);
    }
```

which should be `if (x.right != null)`, of course.

Your `insert` code has the lines

```
    Node tmp = getParent(t,z);
    tmp = y;
```

where you assign to `tmp` and immediately assign to it again. It doesn't seem to me that you need these lines at all, since you don't use `tmp` further on. At this moment, you have `y` being the node to whose child `z` gets inserted, so just delete these lines.

Again, in `delete`, you have the lines

```
    if (x != null){
        Node tmp = getParent(t,x);
        tmp = getParent(t,y);
    }
```

where you don't actually do anything, since `tmp` is not visible outside this snippet. And further on, in `delete`, you repeat the expression `getParent(t,y)`, which can be an expensive operation, so you should compute it only once and assign it to some variable.

But in general, your code, though it seems correct (probably apart from `delete`, which I did not understand completely but which looks suspicious), does not much resemble typical binary tree code. You don't really need the `getParent` and `treeSuccessor` methods to implement `search`, `insert`, and `delete`. The basic structure that you have for `search` works for the others too, with the following modifications:

- with `insert`, when you get to a `null` link, instead of returning `null`, insert the element to that point
- with `delete`, when you find the element, if it has only one (or no) child, replace it with that child, and if it has two children, replace it with either the maximum of the left child tree or the minimum of the right child tree

Both of these require in addition that you keep track of the parent node while descending into the tree, but that's the only modification you need to make to `search`. In particular, there is never any need to go upwards in the tree (which `treeSuccessor` will do).

Comment: with those tmp nodes, ie Node tmp = getParent(t,x); tmp = getParent(t,y); I wanted to set the parent of x at the t to the parent of y node .

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to work: `tmp` is only a reference to the node, and assigning to it will just change where the reference points to, it will not change the object referred to. In any case, you cannot necessarily perform the operation you wanted in a binary tree: what if the parent of `y` already had two children? In that case you could not set it as the parent of `x` too. All manipulation should be by modifying where the child links point to. Keeping track of the parent node of your current node helps here.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your implementation got nothing to do with object orientation (except using objects). The insert and delete operations for example should operate ON the Tree.

Besides, I would recommend to implement the Node class as a static member of the Tree class.

```
public class Tree {
    private Node root = null;

    // remainder omitted

    public boolean insert(int element) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            root = new Node(element);

            return true; // empty tree, Node could be inserted, return true
        }

         Node current = root; // start at root
         Node parent;         // the current Node's parent

         do {
             parent = current;

             if (element < current.element) {
                 current = current.left; // go to left
             } else if (element > current.element) {
                 current = current.right; // go to right
             } else {
                 return false;  // duplicates are NOT allowed, element could not be inserted -> return false

         } while (current != null);

         Node node = new Node(element);

         if (element < current.element) {
             parent.left = node;
         } else {
             parent.right = node;
         }

         return true; // node successfully inserted
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    private static class Node { // static member class
        Node left  = null;
        Node right = null;
        final int element;

        Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

...what is up with your delete code? It doesn't make a lot of sense. I would consider rewriting it in a more logical way. Without the meaningless single-letter variable names. And add comments!

One possible algorithm is:

```
Get the parent of the node to delete
Get the right-most node of the left subtree, or the leftmost node of the right subtree
Remove the node to delete and replace it with the node you found
Rebalance the tree
```

...or, if you want to hack up this stuff so it's right, I'd start looking at the

```
if (x != null){
    Node tmp = getParent(t,x);
    tmp = getParent(t,y);
}
```

part, because that's *clearly* wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to side with Anon and go for the rewrite. The null pointers come from your `getParent` function (which explicitly returns nulls along other things). So I would start there and fix the function(s) so that they return one thing and one thing only at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

***Here is the complete Implementation of Binary Search Tree In Java
insert,search,countNodes,traversal,delete,empty,maximum & minimum node,find parent node,print all leaf node, get level,get height, get depth,print left view, mirror view***

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.experimental.max.MaxCore;

class BSTNode {

    BSTNode left = null;
    BSTNode rigth = null;
    int data = 0;

    public BSTNode() {
        super();
    }

    public BSTNode(int data) {
        this.left = null;
        this.rigth = null;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BSTNode [left=" + left + ", rigth=" + rigth + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }

}


class BinarySearchTree {

    BSTNode root = null;

    public BinarySearchTree() {

    }

    public void insert(int data) {
        BSTNode node = new BSTNode(data);
        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            return;
        }

        BSTNode currentNode = root;
        BSTNode parentNode = null;

        while (true) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            if (currentNode.data == data)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicates nodes note allowed in Binary Search Tree");

            if (currentNode.data > data) {
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
                if (currentNode == null) {
                    parentNode.left = node;
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.rigth;
                if (currentNode == null) {
                    parentNode.rigth = node;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int countNodes() {
        return countNodes(root);
    }

    private int countNodes(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int count = 1;
            count += countNodes(node.left);
            count += countNodes(node.rigth);
            return count;
        }
    }

    public boolean searchNode(int data) {
        if (empty())
            return empty();
        return searchNode(data, root);
    }

    public boolean searchNode(int data, BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            if (node.data == data)
                return true;
            else if (node.data > data)
                return searchNode(data, node.left);
            else if (node.data < data)
                return searchNode(data, node.rigth);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean delete(int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Tree is Empty");

        BSTNode currentNode = root;
        BSTNode parentNode = root;
        boolean isLeftChild = false;

        while (currentNode.data != data) {
            parentNode = currentNode;
            if (currentNode.data > data) {
                isLeftChild = true;
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            } else if (currentNode.data < data) {
                isLeftChild = false;
                currentNode = currentNode.rigth;
            }
            if (currentNode == null)
                return false;
        }

        // CASE 1: node with no child
        if (currentNode.left == null && currentNode.rigth == null) {
            if (currentNode == root)
                root = null;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = null;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = null;
        }

        // CASE 2: if node with only one child
        else if (currentNode.left != null && currentNode.rigth == null) {
            if (root == currentNode) {
                root = currentNode.left;
            }
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = currentNode.left;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = currentNode.left;
        } else if (currentNode.rigth != null && currentNode.left == null) {
            if (root == currentNode)
                root = currentNode.rigth;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = currentNode.rigth;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = currentNode.rigth;
        }

        // CASE 3: node with two child
        else if (currentNode.left != null && currentNode.rigth != null) {

            // Now we have to find minimum element in rigth sub tree
            // that is called successor
            BSTNode successor = getSuccessor(currentNode);
            if (currentNode == root)
                root = successor;
            if (isLeftChild)
                parentNode.left = successor;
            else
                parentNode.rigth = successor;
            successor.left = currentNode.left;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private BSTNode getSuccessor(BSTNode deleteNode) {

        BSTNode successor = null;
        BSTNode parentSuccessor = null;
        BSTNode currentNode = deleteNode.left;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            parentSuccessor = successor;
            successor = currentNode;
            currentNode = currentNode.left;
        }

        if (successor != deleteNode.rigth) {
            parentSuccessor.left = successor.left;
            successor.rigth = deleteNode.rigth;
        }

        return successor;
    }

    public int nodeWithMinimumValue() {
        return nodeWithMinimumValue(root);
    }

    private int nodeWithMinimumValue(BSTNode node) {
        if (node.left != null)
            return nodeWithMinimumValue(node.left);
        return node.data;
    }

    public int nodewithMaximumValue() {
        return nodewithMaximumValue(root);
    }

    private int nodewithMaximumValue(BSTNode node) {
        if (node.rigth != null)
            return nodewithMaximumValue(node.rigth);
        return node.data;
    }

    public int parent(int data) {
        return parent(root, data);
    }

    private int parent(BSTNode node, int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        if (root.data == data)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");

        BSTNode parent = null;
        BSTNode current = node;

        while (current.data != data) {
            parent = current;
            if (current.data > data)
                current = current.left;
            else
                current = current.rigth;
            if (current == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(data + " is not a node in tree");
        }
        return parent.data;
    }

    public int sibling(int data) {
        return sibling(root, data);
    }

    private int sibling(BSTNode node, int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        if (root.data == data)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");

        BSTNode cureent = node;
        BSTNode parent = null;
        boolean isLeft = false;

        while (cureent.data != data) {
            parent = cureent;
            if (cureent.data > data) {
                cureent = cureent.left;
                isLeft = true;
            } else {
                cureent = cureent.rigth;
                isLeft = false;
            }
            if (cureent == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Parent node found");
        }
        if (isLeft) {
            if (parent.rigth != null) {
                return parent.rigth.data;
            } else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Sibling is there");
        } else {
            if (parent.left != null)
                return parent.left.data;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Sibling is there");
        }
    }

    public void leafNodes() {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        leafNode(root);
    }

    private void leafNode(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        if (node.rigth == null && node.left == null)
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        leafNode(node.left);
        leafNode(node.rigth);
    }

    public int level(int data) {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty");
        return level(root, data, 1);
    }

    private int level(BSTNode node, int data, int level) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        if (node.data == data)
            return level;
        int result = level(node.left, data, level + 1);
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        result = level(node.rigth, data, level + 1);
        return result;
    }

    public int depth() {
        return depth(root);
    }

    private int depth(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(depth(node.left), depth(node.rigth));
    }

    public int height() {
        return height(root);
    }

    private int height(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.rigth));
    }

    public void leftView() {
        leftView(root);
    }

    private void leftView(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null)
            return;
        int height = height(node);

        for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
            printLeftView(node, i);
        }
    }

    private boolean printLeftView(BSTNode node, int level) {
        if (node == null)
            return false;

        if (level == 1) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            return true;
        } else {
            boolean left = printLeftView(node.left, level - 1);
            if (left)
                return true;
            else
                return printLeftView(node.rigth, level - 1);
        }
    }

    public void mirroeView() {
        BSTNode node = mirroeView(root);
        preorder(node);
        System.out.println();
        inorder(node);
        System.out.println();
        postorder(node);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private BSTNode mirroeView(BSTNode node) {
        if (node == null || (node.left == null && node.rigth == null))
            return node;

        BSTNode temp = node.left;
        node.left = node.rigth;
        node.rigth = temp;

        mirroeView(node.left);
        mirroeView(node.rigth);
        return node;
    }

    public void preorder() {
        preorder(root);
    }

    private void preorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            preorder(node.left);
            preorder(node.rigth);
        }
    }

    public void inorder() {
        inorder(root);
    }

    private void inorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            inorder(node.left);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            inorder(node.rigth);
        }
    }

    public void postorder() {
        postorder(root);
    }

    private void postorder(BSTNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            postorder(node.left);
            postorder(node.rigth);
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        }
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return root == null;
    }

}

public class BinarySearchTreeTest {
    public static void main(String[] l) {
        System.out.println("Weleome to Binary Search Tree");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean yes = true;
        BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();
        do {
            System.out.println("\n1. Insert");
            System.out.println("2. Search Node");
            System.out.println("3. Count Node");
            System.out.println("4. Empty Status");
            System.out.println("5. Delete Node");
            System.out.println("6. Node with Minimum Value");
            System.out.println("7. Node with Maximum Value");
            System.out.println("8. Find Parent node");
            System.out.println("9. Count no of links");
            System.out.println("10. Get the sibling of any node");
            System.out.println("11. Print all the leaf node");
            System.out.println("12. Get the level of node");
            System.out.println("13. Depth of the tree");
            System.out.println("14. Height of Binary Tree");
            System.out.println("15. Left View");
            System.out.println("16. Mirror Image of Binary Tree");
            System.out.println("Enter Your Choice :: ");
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter Value");
                    tree.insert(scanner.nextInt());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter the node");
                System.out.println(tree.searchNode(scanner.nextInt()));
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println(tree.countNodes());
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println(tree.empty());
                break;

            case 5:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.delete(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            case 6:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.nodeWithMinimumValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 7:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.nodewithMaximumValue());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 8:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.parent(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 9:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.countNodes() - 1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 10:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println(tree.sibling(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 11:
                try {
                    tree.leafNodes();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }

            case 12:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the node");
                    System.out.println("Level is : " + tree.level(scanner.nextInt()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 13:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.depth());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 14:
                try {
                    System.out.println(tree.height());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 15:
                try {
                    tree.leftView();
                    System.out.println();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            case 16:
                try {
                    tree.mirroeView();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            tree.preorder();
            System.out.println();
            tree.inorder();
            System.out.println();
            tree.postorder();
        } while (yes);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding following implementation done for binary search tree, kindly look
into that and let me know any feedback required

1. Insertion
2. InOrderTraversal
3. Search
4. Removal

Please take a look at the main method. so, Please provide your's feedback to improve further from my side.

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root;

    public  BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;        
    }
    public BinarySearchTree(int rootData) {
        root = new Node(rootData);
    }

    public void insertElement(int element,Node parent) {

        Node temp = root;
        if(parent!=null) temp = parent;

        if(temp!=null) {
            Node node = new Node(element);
            if(element<temp.getData()) {
                if(temp.getLeft()!=null)
                    insertElement(element, temp.getLeft());
                else
                    temp.setLeft(node);
            }else if(element>temp.getData()) {              
                if(temp.getRight()!=null)
                    insertElement(element, temp.getRight());
                else
                    temp.setRight(node);
            }
        }
    }


    public void traverseInOrder() {
        if(root!=null) {
            traverse(root.getLeft());
            System.out.println(root.getData());
            traverse(root.getRight());
        }
    }

    public void traverse(Node temp) {       
        if(temp!=null) {
            traverse(temp.getLeft());
            System.out.println(temp.getData());
            traverse(temp.getRight());

        }
    }

    public int searchElement(int element,Node node) {

        Node temp = root;
        if(node!=null) temp = node;
        if(temp!=null) {
            if(temp.getData()<element) {
                if(temp.getRight()!=null)
                    return searchElement(element, temp.getRight());             
            }else if(temp.getData()>element) {
                if(temp.getLeft()!=null)
                    return searchElement(element,temp.getLeft());
            }else if(temp.getData()==element){
                return temp.getData();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public void remove(int element,Node node,Node predecer) {

        Node temp = root;
        if(node!=null) temp = node;

        if(temp!=null) {
            if(temp.getData()>element) {
                remove(element, temp.getLeft(), temp);
            }else if(temp.getData()<element) {
                remove(element, temp.getRight(), temp);
            }else if(element==temp.getData()) {
                if(temp.getLeft()==null && temp.getRight()==null) {
                    if(predecer.getData()>temp.getData()) {
                        predecer.setLeft(null);
                    }else if(predecer.getData()<temp.getData()) {
                        predecer.setRight(null);
                    }
                }else if(temp.getLeft()!=null && temp.getRight()==null) {
                    predecer.setRight(temp.getLeft());
                }else if(temp.getLeft()==null && temp.getRight()!=null) {
                    predecer.setLeft(temp.getRight());
                }else if(temp.getLeft()!=null && temp.getRight()!=null) {
                    Node leftMostElement = findMaximumLeft(temp.getLeft());
                    if(leftMostElement!=null) {
                        remove(leftMostElement.getData(), temp, temp);
                        temp.setData(leftMostElement.getData());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public Node findMaximumLeft(Node parent) {
        Node temp = parent;
        if(temp.getRight()!=null)
            return findMaximumLeft(temp.getRight());
        else 
            return temp;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearchTree bs = new BinarySearchTree(10);
        bs.insertElement(29, null);
        bs.insertElement(19, null);
        bs.insertElement(209, null);
        bs.insertElement(6, null);
        bs.insertElement(7, null);
        bs.insertElement(17, null);
        bs.insertElement(37, null);
        bs.insertElement(67, null);
        bs.insertElement(-7, null);

        bs.remove(6, null, null);
        bs.traverseInOrder();}}
```