# Array based linked list primitives?

Tags: arrays, linked-list

I have this question that asks what 10 primitives are required to make an array based linked list from scratch. I am not sure how to answer it because there are more than 10 on our notes and I dont know which ones are not absolutely required. The answer is supposed to be in MS word but I was wondering if you would give me code example so I can understand it better. I have 8 that I believe are required so far. So far I wrote:

- I would need to allocate the memory and so I could use the create primitive as a constructor.
- I need the isEmpty primitive to check if it’s empty.
- The insert primitive is needed to input nodes and it shifts the elements to the right of the insertion point.
- The delete primitive is needed to remove a node. As our notes states it should check to see if the node is there first. If it is then it will be deleted and the elements will shift back.
- The bool exist primitive checks to see if the node exists.
- The destroy primitive reclaims allocated memory when the object is out of scope.
- To implement the nodes I need the next and previous primitives. Next will point to the node and return the next node.
- Previous does the same but for the previous node.
- I need to track where I am is important.

Comment: Assuming "primitive" means "method or field" (sorry, I haven't heard it used in that context before so I was confused), maybe you'd also need a "before-first" and "after-last" reference to tell where the list begins and ends? Assuming the list isn't circular?

Comment: I think the key difference is that you're dealing with an *array* based linked list.

Comment: Ah. Oops. ^^' Bit of an odd "linked" list, but anyways, you'd still need a reference to the block of memory your list resides in, so that would count as a "primitive"? And you'd need to then track where you are or how far into the array you are? I might be remembering my array-based list structures wrongly. Sorry for the misinformation in my previous comment --- I was a bit thrown by the array part.

Comment: There's a lot of information already availble to help you with this problem. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066729/creating-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch - [http://www.programminginterview.com/content/linked-lists](http://www.programminginterview.com/content/linked-lists) - [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) Also, can you post the original question because your description is a little vague. Questions about linked lists generally ask to list all the necessary functions/operations for a linked list implementation. For instance [http://w