# How to produce a functional LinkedList Class?

Tags: java, oop, linked-list

As part of an assignment I am having to produce a LinkedList class called Registry. It is intended to be part of a simple student registration system with an interface.

Unfortately, I have literally hit a wall and have no idea on what to do next with what I am doing here. The Registry class is just intended to manage a linked list of students called studentList.

Below is the current, rather incomplete class I have made so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Registry 
{
   LinkedList<Student> studentList;

   public Registry()
   {

   }

   public void addStudent(Student aStudent)
   {
      studentList.add(aStudent);
   }

   public void deleteStudent(int studentID)
   {
      studentList.remove(studentID);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      return getClass().getName() + 
   }

   public String format()
   {
      System.out.format(studentList);
   }
}
```

Now, my main worry is using Student. As part of the assignment, I have had to make another class called Student which create instances of Students, containing forenames, surnames, Student IDs and degree Schemes as strings.

How will I be able to use that sperate class to be added to the LinkedList instanted in Registry? And how can I get the Registry class to fully function?

I will try and provide any additional details on request. I am likely unclear, so if I am, let me know, and I will try and explain as best I can.

EDIT: This is the Student Class as requested:

```
public class Student 
{
   private String foreName;
   private String surName;
   private String studentID;
   private String degreeScheme;

   public Student()
   {

   }

   public void setForeName(String foreName)
   {
       this.foreName = foreName;
   }

   public String getForeName()
   {
       return foreName;
   }

   public void setSurName(String surName)
   {
       this.surName = surName;
   }

   public String getSurName()
   {
       return surName;
   }

   public void setStudentID(String studentID)
   {
       this.studentID = studentID;
   }

   public String getStudentID()
   {
       return studentID;
   }

   public void setDegreeScheme(String degreeScheme)
   {
       this.degreeScheme = degreeScheme;
   }

   public String getDegreeScheme()
   {
       return degreeScheme;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       return getClass().getName() + "[foreName = " + foreName + " surName "
               + surName + " studentID " + studentID + " degreeScheme " 
               + degreeScheme + "]";
   }

   public void format()
   {
       System.out.format("%5s%20s%11s%20s", foreName, surName, studentID, degreeScheme);
   }
}
```

Comment: Create your Student class with the required fields. Create a bunch of objects for the Student class using a parameterized constructor and then add them to Registry class using your defined methods?

Comment: Your Registry class *contains* a linked list. It isn't a linked list in itself. It's not clear what you mean by "how can I get the Registry class to fully function" - what does it *not* do now?

Comment: Isn't the assignment to make your own linked list implementation instead of using the Java built-in LinkedList class?

Comment: @AkashPradhan, I already have a Student Class made, are you suggesting that I should add similar variables to the Registry constructor or am I completely going the down the wrong lines?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I was generally refering to how to get the class to be runnable from the state it is now.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I am not sure if I follow, this part of the assignment is intended to allow for the addition of student instances to a LinkedList and to remove them by student IDs. I can add the Student Class if required?

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. What do you mean by "runnable"? Compilable? You don't "run" a class, unless it's got a `main` method entry point, which would be odd in this case. Now I can see that your `remove` method looks wrong, but you really need to be more specific in your questions. What *exactly* is wrong at the moment?

Comment: @JonSkeet. Let me put it this way, how would this class need to be adjusted to be function as part of a tester class or main class? As for problems, there is nothing I can say specially about it because I'm just looking generally on how to make the class work if I plugged the methods into to a tester.

Comment: Surely the way to do that is to try to write the tester class. Stack Overflow is really aimed at *specific* problems rather than this sort of vague question.

Comment: @JonSkeet then I obviously don't belong on this site because most of my problems with OOP are highly generic. How am I supposed to write a tester when the class here is in the state it is and the fact I am not even sure what I should write for the tester? If I had a fully complete class then maybe I could write one easily.

Comment: It sounds like really you should talk to your tutor/professor/whatever then - or just reread the assignment to find out what you're meant to test. *We* don't know what your assignment says - but you do. Does your current class meet all the requirements? You should be able to tell that. As I say, meeting with a teacher in-person is a much better fit for your current uncertainty than a vague SO question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I won't be able to contact them due to the Easter Break. I'm following a template provided by them but it's obviously just made things more complicated. I will try and look for a different source where the generics are more covered. The class here has all the method headers, I was trying to create methods that would work in a tester class. Because I'm confused on how Student is supposed to work with Registry.

Comment: @SIHB007: `Student` almost certainly shouldn't know anything about `Registry`. The one thing I think you *should* think about is what `remove` is currently doing - it's meant to remove by student ID, but it's currently removing by index in the list.

Comment: If you have `Student` class code please post it!

Comment: @Thinkingcap. Student class has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Tester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Registry r = new Registry();
    r.addStudent(new Student("13", "John", "Doe", "Physics")); // Add a student to the Registry
    r.addStudent(new Student("212", "Jane", "Bow", "Chem")); // Add another Student
    System.out.println(r); // Print the Student List

    r.deleteStudent(212); // Deletes student with ID 212
    System.out.println(r);
  }
}


class Student {
  private String studentID;
  private String foreName;
  private String surName;
  private String degreeScheme;

  public Student(String studentId, String foreName, String surName, String degreeScheme) {
    this.studentID = studentId;
    this.foreName = foreName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.degreeScheme = degreeScheme;
  }

  public void setForeName(String foreName) {
    this.foreName = foreName;
  }

  public String getForeName() {
    return foreName;
  }

  public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
  }

  public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
  }

  public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
  }

  public String getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
  }

  public void setDegreeScheme(String degreeScheme) {
    this.degreeScheme = degreeScheme;
  }

  public String getDegreeScheme() {
    return degreeScheme;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[foreName = " + foreName + " surName " + surName + " studentID "
        + studentID + " degreeScheme " + degreeScheme + "]";
  }

  public void format() {
    System.out.format("%5s%20s%11s%20s", foreName, surName, studentID, degreeScheme);
  }
}


class Registry {
  LinkedList<Student> studentList;

  public Registry() { // Creates studentList
    studentList = new LinkedList<>();
  }

  public void addStudent(Student aStudent) {
    studentList.add(aStudent);
  }

  public void deleteStudent(int studentID) {
    int index = searchList(studentID); // Gets index of the student in the Registry
    if (index == -1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student not found");
    // Since studentList is implemented as LinkedList, .remove removes element at specified position
    studentList.remove(index);
  }

  // Search by studentID , if found, return position in the list
  private int searchList(int studentID) {
    Iterator<Student> it = studentList.iterator();
    int count = -1;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      count++;
      Student temp;
      temp = it.next();
      if (Integer.parseInt(temp.getStudentID()) == studentID) {
        return count;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  //Suggestions to improve the toString are welcome
  public String toString() {
    for (Student student : studentList) {
      student.format();
      System.out.println();

    }

    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: the only nitpick I have is I am following a specfic template, and I have to keep studentID as an int in the Registry class. Is there any way to remove the student otherwise?

Comment: But your `Student `class says `studentID` is String (Updated the answer)

Comment: Yes, but I am having to use a template provided by the tutors. String and int studentIDs were specifally used.

Answer (score -2):

In any data structure there are three functions that almost always require implementation:

1. Insertion
2. Searching
3. Deletion

---

Let me begin by clarifying what the general Linked List structure consists of.
The linked list works by operating on *nodes*. Each node contains the actual data you want to store/modify/access.

- **Registry**: This should be responsible for maintaining the structure and providing a way of inserting/searching for/deleting specific nodes in the list.
- **Student**: Stores the data and controls how it is accessed and modified

So far, you have your *Registry* framework created appropriately. (Although you will want to implement a search method.)

For your student class, you simply create the member variables of the class that you need, as well as the appropriate getters/setters for them.

```
public class Student {
   private String id;
   private String forename;
   private String surname;
   private String degreeScheme;
   private Student next;  // Maintains a reference to the next node in the list

   Student () {
    //Default constructor values
   }

   Student (String id, String forename, String surname, String degreeScheme, Student next) {
      this.id = id;
      this.forename = forename;
      this.surname  = surname;
      this.degreeScheme = degreeScheme; 
      this.next = next;
   }

   public void setID (String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getID () {
      return id;
   }

   public void setforename (String forename) {
      this.forename = forename;
   }

   public String getforename () {
      return forename;
   }

   public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
   }

   public String getSurname () {
      return surname;
   }

   public void setDegreeScheme(String degreeScheme) {
      this.degreeScheme = degreeScheme;
   }

   public String getDegreeScheme () {
      return degreeScheme;
   }

   public void setNext (Student next) {
      this.next = next;
   }

   public Student getNext () {
      return next;
   }
} //End Student Class
```

---

This should be a good base to get you started. Remember, when creating data structures you'll avoid a lot of headaches by making sure that you have a clear **separation of concerns.** Make the student class purely responsible for storing and maintaining the data, and let the Registry class be responsible for maintaining the structure itself!

At this point, you can utilize the Student class within your Registry class, just insert the nodes as you want, search for them, delete them as needed.

Comment: "This should be a good base to get you started." I disagree. For one thing, it screams "separation of concerns" at me - why mix the idea of "linked list" and "Student information" into a single class at all? A `LinkedList<Student>` as per the OP's `Registry` class is a *much* better idea. Additionally, I'd encourage the OP to consider making `Student` immutable (for the normal reasons), and follow normal Java naming conventions. I can't see that this code answers the question (which IMO is too vague to answer at the moment) - it just gives a bad suggestion for the Student class.

Comment: Well, You would implement the student class as your linked list in the registry class. @JonSkeet   This is creating the nodes of the list, to be used in the registry class. IMO, this code shows how the structure of his "nodes" of the list are laid out. This is pretty straight-forward to implement.

Comment: But it's mixing the concerns of "I want a linked list" and "I want a student". What if at some point the students should be stored in a set instead? At that point, the "next" field is irrelevant. It's fundamentally not part of the state of a student - it's part of the state of a node in a linked list, so should be kept there.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's pretty trivial if you ask me, at that point you could literally just remove that field. Also, OP never mentions about a possible need to convert structure.

Comment: But separation of concerns is basic OO as far as I'm concerned - so giving an example which violates it does more harm than good. Anyway, it sounds like the OP already *has* a Student class...

Comment: @Thinkingcap "next" would point to the next node in the linked list. It merely holds the reference. This is how a Custom linked list is implemented lol. Go check any site! Here is one from another SO User: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066729/creating-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch

Comment: @JonSkeet This does NOT violate separation of concerns. The registry class is responsible for searching/insertion/deletion. The student class maintains the data and references and the user does not need to know how they are implemented. Thus, separation of concerns is maintained.

Comment: Your `Student` class is a mixture of "data about the student" and "a linked list node". There's nothing *inherently* linked-list-related in a `Student` class. There's no need to have a "custom" linked list here. Just maintaining a `LinkedList<Student>` in the registry is all that's required. I dare say you do disagree with the downvotes - it would be slightly odd if you didn't - but mine is certainly staying, as you're violating SoC in the very same answer that you're championing it.

Comment: @JonSkeet the student class is the node of the linked-list! Registry is the list. How is this not SoC? I really fail to see.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the feedback all the same. I'll read up more I suppose.

Comment: @Evan Like you said `"next" would point to the next node in the linked list` , It implies that Student need knowledge of its implementation as List, thus violating `SoC`

Comment: @ThinkingCap if you were to do a full implementation of a linked list from scratch, how would you propose to store the reference to the next node?

Comment: @Evan Student is not a List , Registry is!  you can have the references in Register

Comment: @Thinkingcap How would you implement that, differently from what I did

Comment: The reason you would need next pointer is to access the elements, But in this case it is all taken care by LinkedList named Registry. Think of Student as the `data` you store in the linked list and not the node itself  . Look at `it.next()` of `searchList` method of my program, If you still need clarity I recommend updating your answer with `main` function

Comment: @Thinkingcap I think I realize what both yourself and JonSkeet are saying; if you were to implement a Linked List from scratch, you would still create the "Node" class and each node would consist of a Student instance. Then the List itself would be maintained in a separate class, to maintain SoC.