# What is the best way to print a whole linked-list if the user did not instantiate any nodes?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes

How can I print a whole **Linked-List** if I did not instantiate any **nodes**?

For example, if I instantiate my linked-list **with nodes** like:

```
    LinkedList<String> node1 = new LinkedList<String>("item 1")
    LinkedList<String> node2 = new LinkedList<String>("item 2")
    Linkedlist<String> nodeN = new LinkedList<String>("item n")

    Node1.setLink(node2);
    Node2.setLink(nodeN)
```

I can simply iterate through the nodes, starting with the **head node**, and print the list like:

```
    LinkedList<String>currentNode = node1;

    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        System.out.println(currentNode.getElement()); //gets and prints the "item" in that node
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
```

And this works.

But, if I try to instantiate my Linked List **without nodes** like:

```
     LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>("The List");

     newList.add("item A");
     newList.add("item B");
     newList.add("item C");
```

How can I **print** the whole `newList` linked-list?

I tried doing:

```
     System.out.println(newList); //the result is something like classes.LinkedList@15db9742
     System.out.println(newList.getInfo());  //This simply prints the name of the newList which is "The List"
     System.out.println(newList.toString());  // also prints something like classes.LinkedList@15db9742
```

How do I set up a current node (to iterate through `newList`) if I did not instantiate any nodes but only instantiated the list?

EDIT:  My `LinkedList` class as requested (**note**: ignore typos if there are any, because my program compiles and runs fine):

```
      public class LinkedList<T> {
            private LinkedList<T> link;
            private T info;

            protected LinkedList<T> list;
            int numElements;

            public LinkedList()
            {
                numElements = 0;
                list = null;
            }

            public LinkedList(T info) 
            {
                 this.setInfo(info);
                 this.setList(null);
            }

            //ACCESSOR
            public LinkedList<t> getLink() { return link; }
            public void setLink(LinkedList<T> link) { this.link = link; }

            public T getInfo() { return info; }
            public void setInfo(T info) { this.info = info; }

            public LinkedList<T> getList() { return list; }
            public void setList(LinkedList<T> list) { this.list = list; }

            //ADD METHOD
            public void add (T element)
            {
                LinkedList<T> newNode = new LinkedList<T>(element);
                if (list == null) 
                {
                    list = newNode;
                    newNode.setLink(list);                    
                }
                else
                {
                     newNode.setLink(list.getLink());
                     list.setLink(newNode);
                     list = newNode;
                }
                numElements++;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried Arrays.toString(newList)

Comment: @Abdullah No, I'm just starting out to learn about Linked Lists....

Comment: This method would work. It is iterating all variables in the list and returns as string

Comment: Is it your custom implementation of LinkedList?

Comment: @Pavlo Yes.  I'm learning the basics of how linked-list works first.  This isn't the in-built java linked-list.

Comment: Could you then provide code of your LinkedList?

Comment: @Pavlo Sure thing.  It may take a bit to type.  Hang on.

Comment: @Pavlo my LinkedList class is now up.

Comment: What should the output look like if the linked list is empty? For that matter, what does the output look like if the list has 1 node? Two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print your list using `System.out.println()`, you should override `toString` method in your `LinkedList` implementation and iterate through all elements similar to the way you presented in your question:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String listRepresentation = "";
    ListNode<T> currentNode = headNode;

    while (currentNode != null) {
        listRepresentation += currentNode.getInfo() + "\n";
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }

    return listRepresentation;
}
```

But you need to fix your `LinkedList` implementation first to correspond the *linked list* definition. See examples *Chester Cobus* provided in his answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  It was my toString() method that was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Which Java version do you use? I'm using Java 8 and I can just simple print it with:

```
System.out.println(newList);
```

Result is

[item A, item B, item C]

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to print the elements.

```
     LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>();

     newList.add("item A");
     newList.add("item B");
     newList.add("item C");

     for (String str : newList) {
         System.out.println(str);
     }
```

Comment: This is a linked-list... my IDE is saying that it cannot iterate over it as it is not an array.

Comment: I just implemented the code using Eclipse and it is working fine. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse.  Specifically, the error reads: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable".  I'm using a custom Linked-List, not the in-built Java one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using:

```
 LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<String>("The List");

 newList.add("item A");
 newList.add("item B");
 newList.add("item C");


 for(int i = 0; i < newList.size(); ++i)
 {
    System.out.println(newList.get(i)); 
 }
```

Please read this article on implementing your own LinkedList : http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/

and

[Creating a LinkedList class from scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066729/creating-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch)

Comment: Your for-loop works, but it's just my results are all 'null' when iterating to each nodes.

Comment: Are you wrapping the built-in java LinkedList into your own LinkedList class? if yes then this is not a correct way of creating a LinkedList from scratch. Please read the links in my previous replies.