# Using the constructor, create a BST given a pre-order String. (Recursion)

Tags: java, recursion

I'm not too familiar with constructors. We've been working with methods all semester. My idea of going about this is:
1) Check to see if the string is not null
2) Convert the string into a char array
3) establish that the first char in the list is the root
4) split the rest of the array up into left and right (if there are more than one).
and the rest I haven't put much thought into yet because I've been running into trouble with converting a char into a node. The class does not allow a creation of a new node, but a BinaryTree with parameters (data, left, right). My code below does not function how I want it to, but just to give you an idea.

```
public BinaryTree ( String preorderSequence ) {

    String s = preorderSequence;
    Node rootNode;

    if (s.isEmpty())
        return;

    if (s.length() == 1)
        rootNode = new Node(s.substring(0));
    else{

        String chars = s.substring(1);
        String rootChar = Character.toString(s.charAt(0));
        rootNode = new Node(rootChar);
        Node low = null;
        Node high = null;
        String temp = Character.toString(chars.charAt(0));

        //Get the lowest valued character and convert it into low node
        for(int i = 0 ; i < chars.length(); i++){

            String comp = Character.toString(chars.charAt(i));

            if( comp.compareTo(temp) < 0 )
                temp = comp;
        }
        low = new Node(temp);

        //Get the highest valued character and convert it into the high node
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++){

            String comp = Character.toString(chars.charAt(i));

            if( comp.compareTo(temp) > 0)
                temp = comp;
        }
        high = new Node(temp);

        if(s.length()>3)
            new BinaryTree(chars);

        if(((String) rootNode.data).compareTo((String) low.data)<0){
            rootNode.right = low;
            low.right = high;
        }
        else
        if(((String) rootNode.data).compareTo((String) high.data)>0){
            rootNode.left = high;
            high.left = low;
        }
        else{
            rootNode.left = low;
            rootNode.right = high;
        }
    }
    root = rootNode;
}
```

Comment: First if is incorrect, String comparison should be done by x.equals(y), not ==

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052563/binary-search-tree-impelementation-and-java for a clear example of a BST implementation

Comment: For 1) you are actually not comparing the string against null in the code! Correct would be `if( preorderSequence == null)`

Comment: You're if statements look weird. Always use brakets, even if you have only one statement in the if block.

Comment: @Patrick if something looks wierd does not mean it is incorrect, if without brackets is legit

Comment: I got it to work for strings containing 1 or 3 characters, but any more than that my code fails. This is challenging because I can only use a string as a parameter.